solve twist on animated object - custom orientation
I have a regular hexagon with 36 triangle faces.
I have created a custom orientation/workplane.
I can rotate the triangle face on the Y axis using the custom orientation as the edge and it rotates perfectly in alignment.
When I keyframe this motion,  the triangle rotates to the extents  as expected ok,but twists along the custom orientation plane.
I have tried using the Object - Transform - Align to Transform Orientation and also tried various options of the custom , local and global orientations just in case.  However, I am unable to stop the twist but retain the desired rotation of the triangle.
I seek to be able to rotate all 36 triangles individually eventually.
I apologize if any of this explanation is unclear as I am a beginner.
Blend file linked via Blend Exchange - my thanks to those people.





Hi falcon, welcome to BSE. i would recommend three things to attract more people: 1) provide your blend file 2) provide an animation/gif/video how it should look like (can be a link to an animation) 3) provide an animation/gif/video how it looks now. This would make it much more easy to understand what you want instead of reading a lot of text and that's stressful and a bit boring ;)
